# Is it a good practice to use organizations as folders?

Tags: github, multiple-repositories, github-organizations

I've seen on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852982/arrange-repositories-in-folders-on-github) that Github organizations were a solution for "regrouping" repositories, as files in a folder.

But while I was reading [Github organizations documentation](https://github.com/blog/674-introducing-organizations), it appears that organizations were designed to represent a developer group or a company, more than a personal repository assembly.

So my question is: **Is it a good practice to use organizations as folders if I am alone to work on it ?**

I mean, do organizations were designed to be used as folders ? And if not, does a lot of people use it in this way ?