# Create a folder inside GitHub organization

Tags: git, github

I want to create a folder inside gitHub organization and create multiple repos inside it.

I know we can have multiple repos inside organization. But i need in below structure.

Example:

- Organization1

  - Folder1

    - Repo1
    - Repo2
  - Folder2

    - Repo1
    - Repo2

Please let us know whether it is possible ? or what is the best way to fulfill my requirement.

Note: I don't want to create multiple organizations. ***Single Org and multiple folders*** and each folder will have no of repositories.

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible in GitHub

Comment: Something similar has been asked and answered below                                           
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852982/can-i-arrange-repositories-into-folders-on-github

Comment: I think GitLab supports that.