# Github and separating type of repositories into different folders

Tags: git, github, package

Reading several questions and some discussion on the web, like [Can I arrange repositories into folders on Github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852982/can-i-arrange-repositories-into-folders-on-github), I still don’t know how to get this working. For the moment I add the “folder name’ in front of the project, but is of course bad practice.

In my github Repository I would to separate the different kind of projects into their own folder.
F.e Documentation projects and Repositories in the Documents folder, Packages in their folder, Gists in the Gist folder; of course if we can talk about folders.

How can I accomplish that; what should the remote path look like?

Any suggestions about this?
I know f.e how to add several Gists in one repository by using git init in the parent folder but now to create or move it to a parent ‘folder’.

A script is also welcome if that exists.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

**Step 1:**
Create those projects as separate repositories: Documentation, Packages, Gists.

**Step 2:**
Create a main repository, and add the repositories created on Step 1 into main repository as a submodule.

That way you have everything separated into their own folders with their own history of commits and branches. Keep adding/committing to them as separated repos, but you can see them all in one place as folders in the main repository.

Comment: Its much closer then what I got; so I go for it. Thank you.